# Java get method on twilio

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, get, twilio

I am using Twilio API for doing few things in my application.
I want to record the user voice and send it to a java file.
So there is a XML file at the server and it will have get method in it where it will post the data to a java file and java file will operate on it.
Something like->
http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#examples-2

So how that can be done using Java where I want to get the recording from this file, instead of using .php file I have to use Java technology.

How that can be achieved

Comment: Could you please elaborate the requirement, It is not clear to me

Comment: @JigarJoshi I am trying to create an application where the given URL will post the transcript of recording to my jsp file and I will operate on the transcript in my code.

Any idea how can I use JSP for operating data which is sent by server ?

Comment: I know in JSP you use something like-> request.getParameter("id") But here the Twilio will be directly sending me the transcript So there is no such 'id' thing ! –

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to

```
<Record
action="http://foo.edu/handleRecording.php"
method="GET"
maxLength="20"
finishOnKey="*"
/>
```

in the example.  the action attribute defines what callback method will be called.  If you change that to

```
<Record
action="http://foo.edu/handleRecording.jsp"
method="GET"
maxLength="20"
finishOnKey="*"
/>
```

a JSP page would be called.  It's absolutely language-neutral, they just mention php as an example.

Whatever languge `action` is code in, it must be a service that complies to [their specification](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-action), ie the code must be able to handle the three parameters it will receive, `RecordingUrl`, `RecordingDuration` and `Digits`.  See the (excellent) documentation.

Comment: Yes exactly.. so it will mean that I will be able to get that data from the Twilio in my JSP file right?
And in that how should I be getting the data ?

Comment: @AnujKulkarni Read the documentation - the program mentioned in the `action` attribute will, among other things, received an URL of the recorded message.  It will either have to download and store that file, or somehow enqueue that URL for later downloading.  What exactly it does depends entirely on your application.